# How to download/export own passwords stored at Google Passwords?

Tags: google-account, security, export, google-passwords

It seems Google activated central place for storing app/website passwords which is accessible on-line at https://passwords.google.com/ and all the remembered Chrome passwords are synched there across all the linked devices. Which is pretty weird that this happened without my knowledge (previously they were stored on my local computer).

I would like to backup/export these stored passwords as it's [not pretty clear](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/96011/11825) how they're stored or how these passwords are safe on the cloud and move away from it.

I've checked [Accounts Help: Download your data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190) page, but this service is not available on the list in settings at https://www.google.com/settings/takeout.

Answer (score 3):

Google's Password Manager now has an **Export** feature in [desktop Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?hl=en&ref_topic=7439541#zippy=%2Cshow-edit-delete-or-export-saved-passwords), [Android Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?hl=en&ref_topic=7439541&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1#zippy=%2Cshow-edit-delete-or-export-saved-passwords%2Cshow-delete-edit-or-export-passwords), and [iPhone and iPad Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?hl=en&ref_topic=7439541&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1#zippy=%2Cshow-edit-delete-or-export-saved-passwords%2Cshow-delete-edit-or-export-passwords).

It saves a **CSV file** which you can open with any spreadsheet program or (less conveniently) a text editor.

This might not be part of Google Takeout. The exported file needs to be kept in careful confidence, not stored in a large archive and stored on an insecure disk.

On **storage security**, [Google Chrome Help says](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10311524#zippy=%2Chow-we-protect-your-data):

> When you log in to a website while signed in to Chrome, Chrome encrypts your username and password with a secret key known only to your device. Then it sends an obscured copy of your data to Google. Because the encryption happens before Google’s servers get the information, nobody, including Google, learns your username or password.

Comment: I wish Google Takeout warned me that I'd need to export my passwords separately, I thought it would be part of something... If they want to keep that data secure, how about they encrypt it with your account password in some format and include it in the list?

Answer (score 0):

As for workaround, I've installed [Dashlane](https://www.dashlane.com) (a password manager app) where you can automatically import all Google-stored passwords (it should ask on the first run), then using their app you can export them into archive file (such as CSV, Excel or encrypted format). Using this method, I've moved all my passwords from *Google Passwords*, and never used it again.

See also: [How can I export Chrome passwords?](https://superuser.com/q/655294/87805)